# Specify CSL styles on RMarkdown

Tags: r, rstudio, pandoc, r-markdown, csl

I am trying to specify a CSL style on my RMarkdown Document as below

```
---
documentclass: article
fontsize: 12pt
linkcolor: blue
output: pdf_document
bibliography: bibliography.bib
csl: biomed-central.csl
---
```

but it gives me an error

```
pandoc-citeproc.exe: biomed-central.csl: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
pandoc.exe: Error running filter pandoc-citeproc
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 83
```

On
 `Windows 7 64 bit` and `R Version 3.1.2` and `RStudio 0.98.1091`
How can I specify a CSL style.

Comment: the error is very helpful. where is the file? you need to use the path if it's not in the same directory

Comment: the CSL file is under the Pandoc folder `~\AppData\Local\Pandoc`

Comment: do you still get error if you use `csl: ~/appdata/local/pandoc/biomed-central.csl`?

Comment: `pandoc-citeproc.exe: InvalidUrlException "~/appdata/local/pandoc/biomed-central.csl" "Invalid scheme" `

Comment: Thanks @rawr It works if I put the biomed-central.csl on the same folder with the .RMD file

Answer (score 6):

Include the `.csl` file in your working directory. you can download the `.csl` file from [here](https://github.com/Keniajin/styles)

Comment: +1. This works. Is it a bug that I cannot specify a path to the `.csl` in a location other than the working directory?

Comment: just like `LaTeX` everything is within the working directory path.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Keniajin's answer, we can specify an absolute or relative path if we put it in quotes, e.g.

```
csl: "<folder>/biomed-central.csl"  # path to child folder
csl: "../biomed-central.csl"  # path to parent folder
csl: "X:/<folder>/biomed-central.csl"  # absolute path (in windows)
```

Besides, the same we can do with other linked files like `*.bib` or `*.tex`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also specify an absolute path. This works, at least on my Linux system.